# Upload File With Custom Properties in PHP Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have difficulties in setting custom properties in file upload at google drive api using php. Uploading the file is ok, but, I can't set custom properties name. I have check in their [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/properties). But, I can't find it. Below are my upload codes.

```
    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $fileMetadata->setName( 'app property test' );
    $fileMetadata->setProperties( json_encode( array(
        'key'        => 'custom_key',
        'value'      => 'This is value',
        'visibility' => 'PRIVATE',
    ) ) );

    $content = file_get_contents( $file_path );
    $file    = $service->files->create( $fileMetadata, array(
            'data'       => $content,
            'mimeType'   => $mimeType,
            'uploadType' => 'multipart',
        )
    );
```

here is some of the things that I have already tested.

```
//This one doesn't work too

$fileMetadata->setProperties(array(
    'key'        => 'custom_key',
    'value'      => 'This is value',
    'visibility' => 'PRIVATE',
));
```

I also tested with this one, too.

```
    //this is not working 
    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'name' => 'This is file name',
        'appProperties' => array(
            'my_custom_field' => 'My value'
        )
    ));
```

Could anyone advice me how I should set custom properties in google drive upload files. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try changing the default metadata properties first to see if you're doing it the right way?

Comment: Yeah, default meta data properties work fine!